# How to change default gateway nic?

Tags: ubuntu, routing, nic

My `/etc/network/interfaces` looks like this:

```
# The primary network interface
allow-hotplug enp3s0
iface enp3s0 inet dhcp
# iface enp3s0 inet6 dhcp

# USB 3.0 Gigabit Ethernet
allow-hotplug enx00249b170da2
iface enx00249b170da2 inet static
  address 192.168.1.67
  netmask 255.255.255.0

# WiFi
allow-hotplug wlp2s0
iface wlp2s0 inet dhcp
# iface wlp2s0 inet6 dhcp
wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

And `route -n` like this:

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 wlp2s0
25.0.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.0.0.0       U     0      0        0 ham0
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 wlp2s0
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 enp3s0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 enx00249b170da2
```

I would like for `enp3s0` to be the default gateway (and in general take priority over `wlp2s0`)

A crucial requirement is that boot complete in any circumstances, with any of the interfaces missing or down.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/708319/how-to-use-network-metric-to-manage-two-nics-in-one-pc

Comment: @Thomas You're saying I should use Metrics? Do you want to post that as an answer? On another note, the example in the link ends up needing the `auto` stanza, whereas my config doesn't have that, yet all 3 interfaces are usable for me. Is allow-hotplug replacing it in my case?